# SQL search, search for a|b|c|d in a table and return results ordered by number of elements in the record

Tags: sql, search, count, sql-order-by

the question:
there are two tables - DAYS(name), ACTIONS(day_name,name)

records for DAYS are:

```
Sunday, Monday, Wednesday
```

records for ACTIONS are:

```
{eat,sunday},
{sleep,sunday},
{write,sunday},
{drink,sunday}

{eat,wednesday},
{sleep,wednesday},
{write,wednesday},

{eat,monday},
{sleep,monday},
```

i want to search in ACTIONS for the days that have the highest number of curtain actions, and return the results ordered from the higher to the lower.
Meaning: if i search for "eat","sleep", "write", and "drink" - the results will be:
`sunday, wednesday, monday.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    day_name, count(day_name) qty
from
    actions
where 
    name in ('eat', 'sleep', 'write', 'drink')
group by day_name
order by qty desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.name
    FROM ACTIONS a JOIN DAYS d ON a.day_name=d.name
        WHERE a.name IN ('eat', 'sleep', 'write', 'drink')  -- Your search
            GROUP BY a.name
                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this...

```
SELECT day_name, number FROM
(
  SELECT day_name, COUNT(*) 
  FROM ACTIONS 
  WHERE name in ('eat', 'sleep', 'write') 
  GROUP BY day_name
) AS Test
ORDER BY number DESC
```